# Disable Azure Hybrid Connection

Tags: azure, azure-hybrid-connections

I would like to have the ability of enabling\disabling individual Hybrid Connections inside an Azure Relay Namespace.

Looking around the management portal it seems like I can only delete a Hybrid Connection.

Answer (score 0):

As per Azure support, one can essentially disable a hybrid connection  by having 0 listeners connected to it.

To make sure that listeners are not able to connect, we regenerate the SAS key with the Listen privilage.